PowerApp Importing Excel file, columns are being ordered automatically
Importing an excel file which just has column names into PowerApp solutions. I set the import to use first row as headers which I wanted. After this, I looked into the app's data section and notice that the columns are ordered alphabetically which is definitely not what I wanted. I don't see any clear way of keeping the order that I have originally when I imported the column headers. Why is this so difficult?

This a by default settings, you can't change the order. They will always reorder alphabetically. If you want to display over the UI you can just simply point towards the one which you want to display.
